# deleteBack java program

Tags: java

I am doing some exercises on practice-it website. And there is a problem that I don't understand why I didn't pass

Write a method deleteBack that deletes the last value (the value at the back of the list) and returns the deleted value. If the list is empty, your method should throw a NoSuchElementException.

Assume that you are adding this method to the LinkedIntList class as defined below:

```
    // A LinkedIntList object can be used to store a list of integers.
public class LinkedIntList {
    private ListNode front;   // node holding first value in list (null if empty)
    private String name = "front";   // string to print for front of list

    // Constructs an empty list.
    public LinkedIntList() {
        front = null;
    }

    // Constructs a list containing the given elements.
    // For quick initialization via Practice-It test cases.
    public LinkedIntList(int... elements) {
        this("front", elements);
    }

    public LinkedIntList(String name, int... elements) {
        this.name = name;
        if (elements.length > 0) {
            front = new ListNode(elements[0]);
            ListNode current = front;
            for (int i = 1; i < elements.length; i++) {
                current.next = new ListNode(elements[i]);
                current = current.next;
            }
        }
    }

    // Constructs a list containing the given front node.
    // For quick initialization via Practice-It ListNode test cases.
    private LinkedIntList(String name, ListNode front) {
        this.name  = name;
        this.front = front;
    }

    // Appends the given value to the end of the list.
    public void add(int value) {
        if (front == null) {
            front = new ListNode(value, front);
        } else {
            ListNode current = front;
            while (current.next != null) {
                current = current.next;
            } 
            current.next = new ListNode(value);
        }
    }

    // Inserts the given value at the given index in the list.
    // Precondition: 0 <= index <= size
    public void add(int index, int value) {
        if (index == 0) {
            front = new ListNode(value, front);
        } else {
            ListNode current = front;
            for (int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++) {
                current = current.next;
            } 
            current.next = new ListNode(value, current.next);
        }
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof LinkedIntList) {
            LinkedIntList other = (LinkedIntList) o;
            return toString().equals(other.toString());   // hackish
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Returns the integer at the given index in the list.
    // Precondition: 0 <= index < size
    public int get(int index) {
        ListNode current = front;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            current = current.next;
        }
        return current.data;
    }

    // Removes the value at the given index from the list.
    // Precondition: 0 <= index < size
    public void remove(int index) {
        if (index == 0) {
            front = front.next;
        } else {
            ListNode current = front;
            for (int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++) {
                current = current.next;
            }
            current.next = current.next.next;
        }
    }

    // Returns the number of elements in the list.
    public int size() {
        int count = 0;
        ListNode current = front;
        while (current != null) {
            count++;
            current = current.next;
        }
        return count;
    }

    // Returns a text representation of the list, giving
    // indications as to the nodes and link structure of the list.
    // Detects student bugs where the student has inserted a cycle
    // into the list.
    public String toFormattedString() {
        ListNode.clearCycleData();

        String result = this.name;

        ListNode current = front;
        boolean cycle = false;
        while (current != null) {
            result += " -> [" + current.data + "]";
            if (current.cycle) {
                result += " (cycle!)";
                cycle = true;
                break;
            }
            current = current.__gotoNext();
        }

        if (!cycle) {
            result += " /";
        }

        return result;
    }

    // Returns a text representation of the list.
    public String toString() {
        return toFormattedString();
    }


    // ListNode is a class for storing a single node of a linked list.  This
    // node class is for a list of integer values.
    // Most of the icky code is related to the task of figuring out
    // if the student has accidentally created a cycle by pointing a later part of the list back to an earlier part.

    public static class ListNode {
        private static final List<ListNode> ALL_NODES = new ArrayList<ListNode>();

        public static void clearCycleData() {
            for (ListNode node : ALL_NODES) {
                node.visited = false;
                node.cycle = false;
            }
        }

        public int data;          // data stored in this node
        public ListNode next;     // link to next node in the list
        public boolean visited;   // has this node been seen yet?
        public boolean cycle;     // is there a cycle at this node?

        // post: constructs a node with data 0 and null link
        public ListNode() {
            this(0, null);
        }

        // post: constructs a node with given data and null link
        public ListNode(int data) {
            this(data, null);
        }

        // post: constructs a node with given data and given link
        public ListNode(int data, ListNode next) {
            ALL_NODES.add(this);
            this.data = data;
            this.next = next;
            this.visited = false;
            this.cycle = false;
        }

        public ListNode __gotoNext() {
            return __gotoNext(true);
        }

        public ListNode __gotoNext(boolean checkForCycle) {
            if (checkForCycle) {
                visited = true;

                if (next != null) {
                    if (next.visited) {
                        // throw new IllegalStateException("cycle detected in list");
                        next.cycle = true;
                    }
                    next.visited = true;
                }
            }
            return next;
        }
    }

// YOUR CODE GOES HERE

}
```

My work so far is this:

```
public int deleteBack(){
    if(front==null){
         throw new NoSuchElementException();   
    }else{
         ListNode current = front;
         while(current!=null){
            current = current.next;   
         }
         int i = current.data;
         current = null;
         return i;
   }   
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the full definition from the task?  If it were the Collection LinkedList from the API you would use pollLast

Comment: @Woot4Moo I think it's meant as an exercise, so he probably can't use library functions.

Comment: @AndresF. I figured as much, was hoping he would post the rest of the class he has to work with, so I could see what functions are provided.

Answer (score 2):

Don't you want to iterate until the current.next is != null?

What you have now passes the entire list, and your last statements do nothing, since current is null already.

Comment: And even worse, `int i = current.data` will throw a NullPointerException :)

Comment: My thought was that since the last element in a LinkedList always has next = null, but it still has a data in it. So I looped through the whole list to get that last element. But your point was right, it throws a NullPointerException. I think I have to come up with another approach. Can you guys give me any suggestion? Thank you, guys!

Answer (score 1):

Think about the logic you have here

```
while(current!=null){       
    current = current.next;     
}
```

When that loop exits, `current == null`, and then you try to access current's data. Does this point you in the right direction?

Comment: Yeah, I got what you're saying. My thought was that in the last Node of the LinkedList next = null, but there is still a data in it. I'm trying to get that data, that's why I looped through the whole list. But if I loop through it, then it will throw NullPointerException because current = null. So I think I have to come up with another approach. Can you guys give me any suggestion?

Comment: You need to loop until you have access to the 2nd to last object (`while (current.next.next != null)`), store the value in the last object (`current.next.data`), and then delete the last object (make `current.next = null`)

Answer (score 1):

// This is the quick and dirty 
//By Shewan

```
public int deleteBack(){
    if(size()== 0){  throw new NoSuchElementException();    }
    if(front==null){ throw new NoSuchElementException();  
    }else{

        if(front.next == null){
              int i = front.data;
              front = null;
               return i;
        }


         ListNode current = front.next;
         ListNode prev= front;

         while(current.next!=null){
             prev = current;
            current = current.next;   
         }
         int i = current.data;
         prev.next = null;
         return i;
   }   
}
```